# Freeform - limit who can view 'results' page

Tags: plugin-freeform, solspace

I've got a form that redirects to a results page on submission. Results page currently lives at `/form/results/[submission.id]/success/`

The results page shows the user's answers, and a bunch of other results.

Is there a 'best' way to make it so that this results page is only accessible for the current user/session? I don't want to have it be available for any random joe to just try IDs and see someone else's results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that freeform doesn't do it.

The longer answer is that you can cheat with a cookie.

I used a cookie. Used this plugin: https://github.com/nystudio107/cookies

In Freeform's admin, I created a hidden field called "cookie validator" and added it to my form.

On the page that my form lives on /form/, I added a cookie that sets a value of a large random number.

```
{% set randomNumber = random(9999999999) %}
{{ setCookie('formcookie', randomNumber, now | date_modify("+1 hour").timestamp ) }}

{{ form.render }}

{% set cookievalueJS %}
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#form-input-cookievalidator').val("{{ randomNumber }}");
 });
{% endset %}
{% includeJs cookievalueJS %}
```

This creates a random number first. Then sets a cookie with that number as a value. And then sets the input field to have that same number.

Then, on my form results page /form/results/

Instead of using an 'isSuccess' check, I check for the cookie & field value...

```
{% set submissionId = segment2 %}
{% set form = craft.freeform.form('myForm') %}
{% set submission = craft.freeform.submissions({
    id: submissionId,
    form: formHandle,
}).first() %}

{% if myCookie  ==  submission.cookievalidator %}
  {# render all the submission data here #}
{% else %}
  {# show the "nothing to show here" page #}
{% endif %}
```

NOTE: I'm going to move this to an all https site eventually, and will probably have to swap the cookie to be a securecookie. But that's pretty straightforward with the cookie plugin.